# What are the main differences, in the compute resources, between left join and cross join?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, left-join

I am very new in spark configuration resources and I would like to understand the main differences between using a left join vs cross join in spark in resources/compute behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If supplied record volume and spark configurations(cores and memory) being the same, *I guess the major gain will be from underlying filtering of rows(join condition) for non-cartesian joins utilizing relatively lesser cores and memory.*

***When both of your tables have a similar size/record count:***

**Cartesian or Cross joins** will be extremely expensive as they can easily explode the number of output rows.

Imagine 10,000 X 10,000 = 100 million

*all rows from corresponding datasets will be read, sorted, and write (n cores) and fit into memory for join thus having larger footprint*

**Inner/Outer Joins** will work on the principles of map/reduce and co-locality

*by *filtering* rows matching join condition(map stage) from data tables using n cores followed by shuffle and sort on local executors and output result(reduce).*

**But, when one of your tables has a smaller size/record count:**

*the smaller table will be read, build a hashtable and write it using (maybe) a single partition i.e. broadcast to each executor reading X partitions of a larger table*